# VB.NET : copy string1 valeur from the resource to the clipboard

Tags: vb.net

How to copy string1 value from the resource to the clipboard ?

```
Dim content As Integer = My.Resources.String1
Clipboard.GetText(My.Resources.String1)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8dRR.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: `content` should be a String, and you want `Clipboard.SetText` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetText(My.Resources.String1)
```